# Bounds of integral in Power function

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Here is the question:

Let $X_1,X_2$ be iid uniform $(\theta,\theta+1)$. For testing $H_0:\theta=0$ versus $H_1: \theta>0$, we have two competing tests:

$\hspace{15mm}\phi_1(X_1):$Reject $H_0$ if $X_1 > .95$,

$\hspace{15mm}\phi_2(X_1,X_2):$Reject $H_0$ if $X_1 +X_2 > c$.

Find the value of c so that $\phi_2$ has the same size as $\phi_2$.

Attempt:

Size for $\phi_1$ is $\alpha_1 = P(X_1 > .95|\theta=0)=.05$

Size for $\phi_2$ is $\alpha_2 = P(X_1 +X_2 > C|\theta=0)=.05$

I'm trying to understand what the bounds for the integrals are , but I'm not able to figure them out:

$\int\int1dx_1dx_2 = \alpha$

If I can solve this integral and for c, I can set $\alpha =.05$ and find the critical value.

Edit: I have located the bounds in the solution manual of Casella and Berger, but I do not understand how to derive them. Also, I'm not sure why C is between 1 and 2.

From Casella and Berger:

$1 \leq C \leq 2$

$\large\int_{1-C}^1\int_{C-X_1}^1dx_1dx_2$

Answer (score 0):

See to find the size you need to find the conditional probability given that your null hypothesis that is $\theta=0$ is true. In that case the bounds will be $(0,1)$ where I put the value $\theta=0$ in the given bounds $(\theta,\theta+1)$.

Comment: I located the bounds, but I'm not sure how to derive them.